# Failed to delete the a comment on post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to delete a comment on a post, but I'm unable to find the comment. When I'm `console.log(post.comments)` it shows me all the comments but still, I can't find the comment. The error was `Comment not found` which I wrote to find that comment is still there or not. But the comment was there I matched the id with it. Help me I'm new to NodeJs. Help me to fix this

*As a frontend I'm using react and redux I think the problem is in the backend, I've also tested with the postman. Can't delete the comment from postman.

### here is the comment route and controller

```
router.route('/:id/comment/:comment_id').delete(protect, deleteComment);
```

---

```
export const deleteComment = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

  const comment = post.comments.find(
    (comment) => comment._id === req.params.comment_id
  );

  if (!comment) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('Comment not found');
  }

  //Check User

  if (comment.user.toString() === req.user._id.toString()) {
    post.comments = post.comments.filter(
      ({ id }) => id !== req.params.comment_id
    );

    await post.save();

    return res.json(post.comments);
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('User not authorized');
  }
});
```

### here is the post model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Please Author is required'],
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
    },
    isLiked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    isDisLiked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    likes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    disLikes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    comments: [
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
        },
        text: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        name: {
          type: String,
        },
        pic: {
          type: String,
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
      },
    ],
    categories: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'modified_at' },
  }
);

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

export default Post;
```

Comment: If you do a console.log(post.comments) after the findById it prints the comments or return empty ?

Comment: @DiegoBascans  If I do `console.log(post.comments)` it prints all the comments had in that post. Then when I try to find by id it shows undefined

Comment: That's probably because you are comparing the Ids, one it comes from the query is an Object and the id that you are sending is a string I assume.

Comment: @DiegoBascans What should I do I'm out of solutions

Comment: @DiegoBascans Thanks I checked the using `typeof` and you are right one is a string and the other is an object to convert it using `toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access to the `_id` you are accessing the instance of the **ObjectId**

You should try to compare with the `id`, that is a string representation of the `_id`

```
const comment = post.comments.find(
    (comment) => comment.id === req.params.comment_id
  );
```

Comment: I found another way `comment._id.toString() === req.params.comment_id`

Comment: You can avoid the .ToString since you already have the property, but that is as you wish

Comment: I used your way